# How to Filter and Send Data from a Json Array per Category?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, collections

Let's say I have:

```json
{
  "cmds": [
    {
      "name": "ban",
      "category": "Moderation"
    },
    {
      "name": "meme",
      "category": "Fun"
    },
    {
      "name": "joke",
      "category": "Fun"
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I filter those commands and send:
Format:
***Category Name***
Commands

Ex:
***Fun***
meme, joke

***Moderation***
ban

(In Node.JS)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Array.reduce()` method for this. Something like this should work:

```js
const obj = {
  "cmds": [
    {
      "name": "ban",
      "category": "Moderation"
    },
    {
      "name": "meme",
      "category": "Fun"
    },
    {
      "name": "joke",
      "category": "Fun"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(obj.cmds.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
  if (!acc[curVal.category]) {
    acc[curVal.category] = [];
  }
  acc[curVal.category].push(curVal.name);
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

The above code will get me an object contains all the categories with array of names under them:

```json
{
  "Moderation": [
    "ban"
  ],
  "Fun": [
    "meme",
    "joke"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and build an object. When same key of category then aggregate values (name)

```js
const process = (arr) => {
  const result = {};
  arr.forEach(({ name, category }) => (result[category] ??= []).push(name));
  return result;
};

const data = {
  cmds: [
    {
      name: "ban",
      category: "Moderation",
    },
    {
      name: "meme",
      category: "Fun",
    },
    {
      name: "joke",
      category: "Fun",
    },
  ],
};

console.log(process(data.cmds))
```